# Whats happening in this for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, comparison-operators

whats happening in the first statement of the for loop? I can not seem to wrap my head around why 1 == 2 would be acceptable because its a comparison and not a value assignment.

```
char ch = 120;
unsigned char x = 1;
unsigned int y = 1;
for(1 == 2; ch > 0; ch++) {
  printf("%d\n", ch);
  x <<= 1;
  y *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a useless statement that the compiler will optimize away. The first statement in the `for` does not need to be an assignment, it is just build to be succinct/readable way to loop over a set of values. You can expand the `for` loop into a `while` and it may make it clearer:

```
1 == 2; // does nothing, likely emits compiler warning.
while( ch > 0 )
{
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    x <<= 1;
    y *= 2

    ch++;
}
```

If you want to use a for loop for the post iteration expression but have already initialized your variables, you can use the null statement as the first expression:

```
for( ; ch > 0; ch++ ){ /* ... */ }
```